# jQuery Select2 3.5.2 set value in dynamically created dropdown

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using older version of select2  - in which to bind an array to a select , I need to use `<input type="text">` . Is it possible to set the value of the select to particular one on some action , say a click . I went through many questions in stack overflow , but no solution seems to work in case of `<input type="text">` .

Here is my code

```js
var value = [{
  id: 0,
  text: 'enhancement'
}, {
  id: 1,
  text: 'bug'
}, {
  id: 2,
  text: 'duplicate'
}, {
  id: 3,
  text: 'invalid'
}, {
  id: 4,
  text: 'wontfix'
}]


$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".lang").select2({
    data: value
  })


});

$("#btn").click(function() {
  $(".lang").select2('val', 'bug');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<input class="lang" type="text" style="width:100px">
<input class="lang" type="text" style="width:100px">
<input class="lang" type="text" style="width:100px">

<button id="btn">Click Here</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated answer to support multiple selects to be changed in the same time (class) and use data (id & text) object instead of value (id)

1. Why do you call twice select2() ?
2. If you want to select something, you need to pass the value as the parameter, not the description

quick solution: `$("#lang").select2('val', 1);`

```js
var value = [{
  id: 0,
  text: 'enhancement'
}, {
  id: 1,
  text: 'bug'
}, {
  id: 2,
  text: 'duplicate'
}, {
  id: 3,
  text: 'invalid'
}, {
  id: 4,
  text: 'wontfix'
}]


$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".lang").select2({
    data: value
  })


});

$("#btn").click(function() {
  $(".lang").select2('val', 1);
});

$("#btn-2").click(function() {
  $(".lang").select2('data', {id: 0, text: 'enhancement'});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<input id="lang_1" type="text" class="lang" style="width:100px"><br />
<input id="lang_2" type="text" class="lang" style="width:100px"><br />
<input id="lang_3" type="text" class="lang" style="width:100px"><br />

<button id="btn">Set all to value 1</button><br />
<button id="btn-2">Set all to data (id & text object)</button>
```

Comment: Something i found working in this fiddle. - https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadtarawneah/o0uxjjtq/23/ . thanks for the answer.

Comment: I have changed the question slightly , actually problem is with the selector , if I'm using class The above code is not working. I have more than one select boxes and have to use `class` instead of `id`

Comment: you want to manually update the value on multiple selects in the same time with the same value ?

Comment: I have edited my answer as well, now it supports multiple selects changed in the same time with one button click (using class) - it works

Comment: Is there any way to set a particular text as the selected value ?

Comment: In this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadtarawneah/o0uxjjtq/23/ - value is set as text. That is why i used select two times.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107314/discussion-between-qdev-and-sooraj-chandran).

Comment: no, in that fiddle, first .select2() transforms the input into select2 object (what you already have done on ready), and second one selects the default value

Comment: I have edited the answer to support setting data object (id & text)